# Internet explorer 8 simulate event capturing

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, events, capture

I want to implement the event capturing model in IE8. In other words, I want the parent event handler to fire before all the child elements handlers. There are ways to workaround the effects of bubbling in my code, but in the end I create more problems for myself that way. And the visual effect of the event handlers firing sequence cannot be overcome. I am thinking about some kind of stack that keeps the event handlers and then executes them in reverse order. Any ideas, any kind of experience in that task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately IE doesn't support this, so your only option is to simulate it somehow. You could have a single DOM event handler on the outermost element and create your own system of event listener registration.